# Como faço para obter uma URL de angularJs em PHP

Tags: php, angularjs, url

Não consigo obter o URL atual de angular em PHP, já tentei usar $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"], além disso, vem o caminho original do arquivo ...

URL original:
http://link.com.br/ead/moodle2017/#/aulas/39

Eu preciso do parâmetro para manipular no PHP.

Answer (score 1):

Na URL

```
http://link.com.br/ead/moodle2017/#/aulas/39
```

A parte que define o recurso é

```
http://link.com.br/ead/moodle2017/
```

enquanto que a parte que define o estado é

```
                                  #/aulas/39
```

O problema que você está enfrentando é que a requisição `GET` feita ao servidor só possui, como referência no cabeçalho `referrer`, a informação do recurso.

Uma opção então seria enviar a URL capturada via javascript, utilizando `window.location` por exemplo.